# How do I bind two instances of an object in WPF (Or can I?)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to bind two different instances of an object to different parts of a form and I am not finding any help in how to do it, which makes be believe that I am on the wrong path. Especially since this seems like it would be a very common task to do in WPF binding.

So before I continue down this road any further I want to ask this question. Is it possible to bind two different controls with two different DataContexts? For instance I have a Home team and a Visitors team on my form and I want to use the same object for both of them. I had thought it would just be a matter of creating two DataContexts (DataContext1 & DataContext2) and then setting the binding for each one but couldn't  find a sample of anything like that. Here is what I have, which is a contrived example of what I am trying to do.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Results team1 = new Results() { StoreId = 101, Score = 10 };
        Results team2 = new Results() { StoreId = 102, Score = 15 };

        this.DataContext = team1;
        //this.DataContext = team2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a proper ViewModel which contains these data items as properties:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Results Team1 {get;set;}

    public Results Team2 {get;set;}
}
```

then:

```
DataContext = new ViewModel
              {
                 Team1 = new Results { StoreId = 101, Score = 10 },
                 Team2 = new Results { StoreId = 102, Score = 15 },
              };
```

Otherwise, if you want to introduce the concept of a *"List of Results"* in your UI, then use an [`ItemsControl`](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) and an `ObservableCollection<Results>`.

Comment: That worked perfectly. One note for anyone looking at this later. The two semicolons after the Team...new Results...{....} should be removed and a coma should be put in between the two like this: team1 = new Results { StoreId = 101, Score = 10 }, team2 = new  Results { StoreId = 103, Score = 15 }